# separating a `ReadList` of a CSV file into columns using `Case`

Tags: import, data, dataset, csv-format, column

I have a really large file and would like to determine the pattern required for separating the columns by the different headers.
I attempted to use `Cases` but it's been a long time since I've utilize the function `Cases`.

Mathematica seems to have a very poor source of information when it comes to data manipulation of imported CSV files.

```
raw_data = ReadList["file_name.csv", Word, RecordLists -> True]
```

[image]

The file can be uploaded from: https://ufile.io/mdvjz

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a .csv file but a semicolon separated values file, with missing values and even missing headers. So:

```
data = ReadList["...//rawdatatest.csv"
, Word, WordSeparators -> {";"}, RecordLists -> True, NullWords -> True
]


data[[;; 15, ;; 15]] // Dataset
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a good text for learning importing and "cleaning" of data?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not aware of any except sources here or in documentation of `ReadList` and friends.

Comment: May I know what `data[[;; 15, ;; 15]] // Dataset` does? The `;;` denotes `Span`

Comment: @Physkid I just extracted first 15 rows and columns to show the result, full data is in `data`.

Comment: @Physkid just select `;;` and hit `F1`.

Comment: `travel_time = Flatten[data[[2 ;; 2326, 6]]]`
I'd like to sum up all the values in this column but when I use the `Total` function, I'm not given a sensible output...
Is there something subtle here?

Comment: All those values are strings because it is not clear what to expect. So you need to use `ToExpression` if you want to do calculations.

Comment: `travel_time = ToExpression[Flatten[data[[2 ;; 2326, 6]]]]` Isn't working.

Comment: @Physkid it is for me but `travel_time` is not a valid variable name...

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much. I'll be studying yours codes very carefully and experiment with it!

Comment: `idletime = ToExpression[data[[2 ;; 2326, 15]]]` gives "Invalid syntax in or before "0,0". What is wrong?

Comment: @Physkid how about you start investigating the content by yourself: `InputForm@data[[2 ;; 15, 15]]`